# Display Hash table values in View MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, hashtable

This is how i insert value into a **hashtable** and these *mid,mprize* are model variables.I **need to access it and display it on my View**.I have tried a lot but i failed.

```
     if (Session["cart"] != null)
                {

                    Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Session["cart"];

                    var mydata = new List<cart>
                    {
                        new cart { mid= mid, mprize = mrate },
                    };

                    //Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

                        ht.Add(mid,mydata);

                    Session["Cart"] = ht;
}
```

this is what i have tried to get value

```
 public ActionResult cart()
            {
                Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Session["cart"];

            Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Session["cart"];
            ViewBag.MyData = ht;

    return View();
    }
```

> View

```
  @foreach (var e in ViewData.Model)
        {
          //dont know how to fetch value from e  

        }
```

i just copied above code from google ,And am a newbie in hashtable
and **How to bind this data with my model** ?Because my view is using model binding.
I dont know how to put into my List using keys
Ihave value in the form[image]

Comment: Why are you using hashtable over dictionary / concurrentdictionary?

Comment: Actually i want to put values in a session ,Then the further operation has to perform on the session.To implement multidimensional array i dont know any other solution

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on dictionary and concurrentdictionary. They are more up to date (i.e. generic) versions of hashtable.

Comment: `foreach (int str in c)` would be better as `foreach (var str in c)`.

Comment: tried that too,But not getting

Answer (score 0):

**Method**

```
public ActionResult cart()
        {
            Hashtable ht = (Hashtable)Session["cart"];

            ViewBag.myData = ht;

return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@{
var items = ViewBag.myData;
    */your code for getting data using keys /*
}

  foreach(var it in (List<cart>)ht["hashData"])
                {
                   @it.mid
                }
```

[image]

Comment: how to get "(HashTable)ViewBag.myData;" in View?

Comment: Can i bind it with my model?

Comment: @{
var items = (HashTable)ViewBag.myData;
    */your code for getting data using keys /*
}

Comment: yes you bind it with your model

Comment: it shows the error types of namespace not found at "(HashTable)ViewBag.myData;",Dont know how to call system.collections in VIew

Comment: and how to bind it with my model from controller?(actually i dont know how to work with hashtable,am a noob in this)

Comment: just use it with viewbag and remove hashtable from view 
`var items = ViewBag.myData`

Comment: System.Collections.Hashtable <- this is what am getting in the View when i display @item

Comment: foreach(var it in (List<cart>)ht["hashData"])
                {
                   
                }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201925/discussion-between-miky-and-codeseeker).